# Discrete fractional fourier transform

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis

I have written a code for producing matrix of fractional fourier transform with the help of eigen vectors of fourier transfom matrix. Does anyone know the elements of this matrix ( for example a 4 by 4 matrix with $\alpha$=0.5), so I could check it with my code.

Comment: What are you taking the fractional Fourier Transform of? For example, do you mean the matrix on the top of page [*583*](http://www.waset.org/journals/waset/v19/v19-107.pdf)? Maybe you can show a sample 3x3 and 4x4 matrix to make this all clearer. Regards